# Laravel artisan migrate not creating new table

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

Here I use `php artisan make:migration create_profiles_table` to create an entry of new migration.
And `php artisan migrate:status` to show the migration status:
[image]

After that I typed `php artisan migrate`.

Problem comes: the new migration table is not created.

Any hint for me? Thx

Comment: Did you create the model for the database? Try running composer dump-autoload. Then run again the migration.

Comment: Model is not needed for the migration to work.

Comment: @nevermoi could you paste this migration file? Are all other migrations loaded? Could you update the question with migrate:status after php artisan migrate is called?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I located the issue, it is because  my team mate added exit in one of the migration file. lol

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check each of the migration file about "exit" keyword